# Terminated app due to memory pressure while scrolling pdf file in UIWebview in ios7

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

[image]I am saving the pdf file in application document folder and I am loading that pdf file into web view using the load request method then i am scrolling the loading pdf file in web view then application crashed or terminated due to memory pressure.
"Did receive memory warning method" is calling before terminating the application.
Please provide solution to avoid app termination.Thanks to one and all in advance.

Comment: What device are you testing on?
Do you have some sort of TapRecognizer/SwipeRecognizer on your view?

Comment: I am testing in ipad2 and I am not using any gesture recognizes . Just I am scrolling uiwebview, mean while pdf file is loading,after five or six pages scrolling application is terminating & "due to memory pressure" message appearing on in Xcode while debugging.

Comment: In XCode you have a graph that shows the memory usage, when you open your PDF, does it only start to increase when you start scrolling or already when the website loads?

Comment: I have attached graph screen to show the memory before crashing. Initially memory utilized 31mb & after opening the pdf into web view the memory utilized is 276mb (actual pdf file size 3 mb).after this application terminating

Comment: I think we need your code to be able to help you efficiently.